# Negative numbers not considered when finding smallest number in an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm

I have an NSMutable array of NSNumbers, which were converted from NSInteger values. In the case that  I have a mix of negative and positive numbers, I end up with the result that the smallest positive number is the smallest number overall, even when there are negative numbers. If all of the numbers are negative it will find the smallest one (e.g. -2, -1, -1 will give -2 as the smallest value).

```
self.scoreArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.pOne, self.pTwo...etc];

NSNumber *min = self.scoreArray[0];
for (int i=0; i<[self.scoreArray count]; i++) {
   if (self.scoreArray[i] < min) {
     min = self.scoreArray[i];
   }
NSLog(@"The smallest number is %@", min);
}
```

How can I change this so that the smallest number (including negative numbers) is always correct?

Comment: Does `scoreArray` contains NSNumbers? Do you need to return the instance of the NSNumber that represents the smallest value, or a copy of that instance?

Comment: Yes, `scoreArray` contains NSNumbers. I want to return the instance of the NSNumber.

Comment: Then, try my answer. It compares the integerValues wrapped in the NSNumbers and returns the instance of the NSNumber containing the smallest value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `min` is not an `int`, it is a pointer towards an instance of `NSNumber`.
You have to compare the `integerValues`. Beware that the code below will return you the original `NSNumber`, not a copy.
I am alos assuming that `scoreArray` contains `NSNumber`s.

```
self.scoreArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.pOne, self.pTwo...etc];

NSNumber *min = self.scoreArray[0];
for (int i=0; i<[self.scoreArray count]; i++) {

if ([self.scoreArray[i] integerValue] < [min integerValue]) {
     min = self.scoreArray[i];
   }
NSLog(@"The smallest number is %@", min);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using c-type operates for comparing objects. this will lead to comparison of the pointer address. It is also not necessary to create c type values from objects as shown by Jean, you can just use the `compare:` method. Three different approaches with it:

You could sort the array and just take the first element to gain simpler code

```
NSArray *sortedNumbers = [self.scoreArray  sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSNumber *n1, NSNumber *n2) {
    return [n1 compare:n2];
}];
NSNumber *min = sortedNumbers[0];
```

or your approach can be simplified

```
self.scoreArray = @[self.pOne, self.pTwo...etc];
__block NSNumber *min = @(NSIntegerMax);

[self.scoreArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *n, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([n compare:min] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        min = n;
    }
}];
```

if you don't like block-based enumeration, you should use fast enumeration

```
self.scoreArray = @[self.pOne, self.pTwo...etc];
NSNumber *min = @(NSIntegerMax);

for (NSNumber *n in self.scoreArray) {
    if ([n compare:min] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        min = n;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use KVC to retrieve the minimum value -

```
NSNumber *min = [self.scoreArray valueForKeyPath:@"@min.intValue"];
```